# Need Specific Function Argument Structure in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

There's a certain library that I'm using in MATLAB that requires the input function to be defined as a function with 2 arguments. That is

```matlab
function = @(x, y) ...
```

However, I want to return a variant of a function that takes the input as a single vector. What I mean by this is

```matlab
function = @(x, y) function2([x, y])
```

Now, here's where the problem lies: I want this to this for an n-dimensional `function2` where some coordinates remain fixed. So for a 3-dimensional function, we have the options

```matlab
function = @(x, y) function2([x, y, X(3)])
```

```matlab
function = @(x, y) function2([x, X(2), y])
```

```matlab
function = @(x, y) function2([X(1), x, y])
```

```matlab
function = @(x, y) function2([y, x, X(3)])
```

```matlab
function = @(x, y) function2([y, X(2), x])
```

```matlab
function = @(x, y) function2([X(1), y, x])
```

So, with an increase in the dimension of `function2`, hardcoding just seems impossible. Is there a way to formulate a `function` that'll work for a generic n-dimensional `function2` with `x` and `y` assigned to vary along some `dim1` and `dim2`, where dim1, dim2 <= N

Comment: I'd split the arguments in the function: combining them in the function.

Comment: How do you intend to use these functions? It seems you’ll end up with O(n^2) functions. What do you do with them? Put them in an array?

Comment: Actually, I don't need all the O(n^2) functions. I just need a specific instance of it which is decided on the basis of some random number. But I think I have an idea of how to do it really.
If I add on additional unit vectors with u, v with 1s in the appropriate location, and define a vector of ones with zeros to complement u, v(say, we call this w). Then I can write `function2(X .* w + x .* u + y .* v)`